# Like/Love Reaction Function in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can anyone tell me how to implement the love reaction button in Firebase? 
I have this node in Firebase RealTime Database:

```
Posts
 -L28ejHO7-AHEOyclLsP
     Caption: "lol"
     CurrentUserReaction: "reacted"
     Image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nep..."
     ReactingUser 
         <UserWhoReactedOnthisPostID> : "1"
     Time: "09:55:58"
     TotalReactions: "1"
     Unique: "-L28ejHO7-AHEOyclLsP"
     UserPhoto: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nep..."
     Username: "JustAnotherShit"
```

So, what I did is everytime a user presses the love button, I want to add his userId to ReactingUser.. That is going okay, but the problem I am facing is that, whenver I press the button, it adds the currentUser to ReactingUser node and thats okay, and the CurrentUserReaction sets to "reacted" too. And my recyclerView is populated as:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Posts model, int position) {
                        Context c = getActivity();
                        context = c;
                        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                        viewHolder.setCaption(model.getCaption());
                        viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                        viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage(), c);
                        viewHolder.setCurrentUserImage(model.getUserPhoto(), c);
                        viewHolder.imageViewIfUserClicked(model.getReactingUsers(), c);
                        totalVotes = model.getTotalReactions();
                        uniqueKey = model.getUnique();
                    }
```

`viewHolder.imageViewIfUserClicked(model.getReactingUsers(),c)`is used to populate the view according to FirebaseRealtimeDatabase node "CurrentUserReaction". So, when one user reacts, it is set to "reacted" and other user logs in, it is still reacted though it is not him who reacted to it, but it was previous user. So, any help regarding the this affair? Is my approach right? Or should I go for other thing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything look fine expect the "CurrentUserReaction" node. Don't store that whether user reacted or not in the post node as it's depends on the currentUser.

Since you're storing "ReactingUser", you can check whether the currentUser's id is existing or not in that node. If it exist then that user have reacted.

Add a SingleValueListner to check whether userId exists on "ReactingUser" node for every post.

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Posts model, int position) {
    Context c = getActivity();
    context = c;
    viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
    viewHolder.setCaption(model.getCaption());
    viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
    viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage(), c);
    viewHolder.setCurrentUserImage(model.getUserPhoto(), c);
    totalVotes = model.getTotalReactions();
    uniqueKey = model.getUnique();

    getRef(position).child("ReactedUser").child(currentUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new.ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
          if(snapshot.exists())
              //user have reacted. Update ui
          else
              //user haven't reacted. 
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
  });
}
```

P.S. This works fine but I do feel little bit bad for sending requests again and again for every post. I couldn't find any alternative way to do this. If there's pls tell.

Comment: Where should I put that SingleEventListener? I need to populateView differently for different user, and model.getReactingUser() is not working well, because it checks the "CurrentUserReaction" node . Not the ReactingUser node. Besides, ReactingUser node is not retured by Firebase as it is another child itself... How can I listen to it ?

Comment: Put SingleEventListener inside populateViewHolder(). And don't use model.getReactingUser(), except use the above SingleEventListener to check whether the user have reacted. I edited the answer. Hope it helps.